# Query in Mysql 5.5 is very slow compared to Mariadb 10.2

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I ran following query in **Mysql 5.5** and **Mariadb 10.2**. it took only **4 seconds** to run the query in Mariadb while it took about **6 minutes** in Mysql.

```
SELECT
  ' ' AS max_claim_amount,
  claims_only_A.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      employee.emp_number AS emp_number,
      ' ' AS emp_id,
      ' ' AS emp_name,
      NULL AS estimate_id,
      NULL AS estimate_submitted_date,
      NULL AS estimate_state,
      NULL AS currency_for_reimbursement,
      NULL AS cash_in_advance,
      NULL AS estimate_purpose,
      NULL AS estimate_exp_type,
      NULL AS estimate_foreign_currency,
      NULL AS estimate_exchange_rate,
      NULL AS estimate_amount,
      NULL AS claim_id,
      NULL AS claim_currency_for_reimbursement,
      NULL AS claimed_date,
      NULL AS claim_exp_type,
      cety.id AS claim_exp_type_id,
      claim_cc.currency_id AS claim_foreign_currency,
      cex.exchange_rate AS claim_exchange_rate,
      cex.amount AS claim_amount,
      cex.remarks AS claim_remarks,
      employee.deleted_at AS emp_deleted_at,
      employee.purged_at AS emp_purged_at,
      employee.termination_id AS emp_termination_id,
      employee.emp_lastname AS emp_lastname,
      el.location_id AS emp_location_id,
      employee.job_title_code AS emp_job_title_code,
      employee.work_station AS emp_work_station,
      cr.request_id AS claim_request_id,
      employee.emp_status AS emp_status,
      NULL AS estimate_sort_id,
      cex.id AS claim_exp_id
    FROM
      `claim_request` cr
      LEFT JOIN `claim_expense` cex ON cex.request_id = cr.id
      LEFT JOIN `claim_expense_type` cety ON cex.expense_type_id = cety.id
      LEFT JOIN `_employee` AS employee ON cr.emp_number = employee.emp_number
      LEFT JOIN claim_currency claim_cc ON (claim_cc.id = cex.currency_id)
      LEFT JOIN claim_currency claim_req_cc ON (claim_req_cc.id = cr.currency_id)
      LEFT JOIN _emp_locations el ON(employee.emp_number = el.emp_number)
    WHERE
      cr.id NOT IN (
        SELECT
          claim_request_id
        FROM
          `claim_estimation_claiming`
      )
  ) AS claims_only_A
WHERE
  (claim_request_id, claim_amount) NOT IN (
    SELECT
      claim_request_id,
      MAX(claim_amount)
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          cr.request_id AS claim_request_id,
          cex.amount AS claim_amount,
          cety.name AS claim_expense_type,
          cex.id AS claim_exp_id
        FROM
          `claim_request` cr
          LEFT JOIN `claim_expense` cex ON cex.request_id = cr.id
          LEFT JOIN `claim_expense_type` cety ON cex.expense_type_id = cety.id
        WHERE
          cr.id NOT IN (
            SELECT
              claim_request_id
            FROM
              `claim_estimation_claiming`
          )
      ) AS A
    GROUP BY
      claim_request_id,
      claim_expense_type
  )
```

Explain of the queried run were the followings,

```
-- MYSQL 5.5
+----+--------------------+--------------------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                          | type           | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref                                     | rows | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2>                     | ALL            | NULL             | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                                    | 2876 | Using where                     |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | <derived5>                     | ALL            | NULL             | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                                    | 2876 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  5 | DERIVED            | cr                             | ALL            | NULL             | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                                    | 1131 | Using where                     |
|  5 | DERIVED            | cex                            | ref            | request_id       | request_id       | 5       | dbname.cr.id               |    1 |                                 |
|  5 | DERIVED            | cety                           | eq_ref         | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.cex.expense_type_id |    1 |                                 |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | claim_estimation_claiming | index_subquery | claim_request_id | claim_request_id | 5       | func                                    |    2 | Using index                     |
|  2 | DERIVED            | cr                             | ALL            | NULL             | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                                    | 1131 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DERIVED            | cex                            | ref            | request_id       | request_id       | 5       | dbname.cr.id               |    1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED            | cety                           | eq_ref         | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.cex.expense_type_id |    1 | Using index                     |
|  2 | DERIVED            | employee                       | eq_ref         | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.cr.emp_number       |    1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED            | claim_cc                       | eq_ref         | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.cex.currency_id     |    1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED            | claim_req_cc                   | eq_ref         | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.cr.currency_id      |    1 | Using index                     |
|  2 | DERIVED            | el                             | ref            | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.employee.emp_number |    1 | Using index                     |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | claim_estimation_claiming | index_subquery | claim_request_id | claim_request_id | 5       | func                                    |    2 | Using index                     |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+

-- MARIADB 10.2
+------+--------------+--------------------------------+--------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table                          | type   | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref                                     | rows | Extra                        |
+------+--------------+--------------------------------+--------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | cr                             | ALL    | NULL             | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                                    |  920 | Using where                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | cex                            | ref    | request_id       | request_id       | 5       | dbname.cr.id               |    1 | Using where                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | cety                           | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.cex.expense_type_id |    1 | Using where; Using index     |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | employee                       | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.cr.emp_number       |    1 | Using where                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | claim_cc                       | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.cex.currency_id     |    1 | Using where                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | el                             | ref    | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.employee.emp_number |    1 | Using where; Using index     |
|    4 | MATERIALIZED | cr                             | ALL    | NULL             | NULL             | NULL    | NULL                                    |  920 | Using where; Using temporary |
|    4 | MATERIALIZED | cex                            | ref    | request_id       | request_id       | 5       | dbname.cr.id               |    1 |                              |
|    4 | MATERIALIZED | cety                           | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY          | 4       | dbname.cex.expense_type_id |    1 | Using where                  |
|    6 | MATERIALIZED | claim_estimation_claiming | index  | claim_request_id | claim_request_id | 5       | NULL                                    |    1 | Using index                  |
|    3 | MATERIALIZED | claim_estimation_claiming | index  | claim_request_id | claim_request_id | 5       | NULL                                    |    1 | Using index                  |
+------+--------------+--------------------------------+--------+------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+
```

I tried running sub-queries separately and the sub-queries didn't show any delay in Mysql. The problem seems to be only when the query is run as a whole.

As I feel, according to the explains, the issue seems to be because Mysql 5.5 has more `All` values in type field (it means mysql has to go through all the values in a subset).

Anyone has a better reasoning or Anyway to improve this query?

Comment: This is a very complicated query, and most readers might find it hard to make a meaningful suggestion.  If you can pare down the query to something simpler, which still demonstrates the difference between MySQL and MariaDB, it might help you get an answer faster.

Answer (score 2):

Turn

```
NOT IN ( SELECT ... )
```

into either

```
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ... )
```

or

```
LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NULL
```

Then see if you can get rid of more subqueries.

If those don't speed it up enough, I'll look again.

The likely reason is that MariaDB has a feature that MySQL does not have:  subquery caching.  Also, MySQL has 3 major versions after 5.5, and there are some significant optimization improvements in them.

It would be interesting to see `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` from each server (plus RAM size).  From that, I think I can point out that the caching is in use.

Meanwhile, my goal in the reformulation suggestions is to speed up MySQL (and maybe MariaDB).

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like there is a redundant left join which isn't used anywhere, so it will be helpful to remove it: `claim_req_cc`
2. Try to modify NOT IN to NOT EXISTS, as Rick mentioned.